# How to get updated html data without refreshing the page selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium python, and I am trying to get a element that gets added when I scroll down the page, youtube comment box that gets loaded when you scroll down. However none of the method of finding the element works out, as it seems to me selenium is not aware of the updated data. I have tried using sleeps, implicit and explicit waits but that did not help either.

```html
<textarea id="textarea" class="style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea" rows="1" autocomplete="off" required="" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
```

this is the code that gets added.

What are the ways to get selenium to not store the html until it gets added? or how to tell selenium that there is a new element on the page?

I am using chromedriver, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import 
WebDriverWaitWebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="textarea"]'))
```

Comment: Can you please clarify as to why wait for 60seconds? and how to use the element?

Comment: 60 seconds maybe too long,you can choose a shor time to prevent the page you request doesn't include the element.  use the element,there are many selenium-webdriver's API ,find_element_by_name,find_element_by_tag,find_element_by_xpath,etc. i often use selenium scrapy some  complex page,so the most common metho find_element_by_xpath is my best choice.

Comment: I tried with that, `elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="textarea"]'))`
it raises timeoutexception, i scrolled down the page before using this wait, is that right?

Comment: sorry， i  misunderstand your meaning .  you can  use this                           js="var q=document.documentElement.scrollTop=100000"  
driver.execute_script(js)                         these code let webbroser excute js to scroll .

Comment: Hello, thanks that works but i use `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 880)")` to do that, but that is not the main problem, its that the webdriverwait is not working as it should.

Comment: you still can't get the textArea element?

Comment: you should use print  webdriver.page_source  to confirm the html and js are what you excepted

Comment: I checked the source page there was no textarea element present there

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your application. If your application using AXAX then you will get updated data on page and DOM. Selenium have only able to access on your present DOM so if your application is not having such AXAX calls then you have to referesh the page.